# SQL LCM (get the least common divisor)

Tags: sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/csmPT.png

I have my relatives in the picture. If there is 1 in the ITEMQTY part opposite the data written in the code part, the ITEMQTY part of the data in the code part should not give the least common divisor of each other. If there is no 1 , then dividing each other with the least common divisor .

Comment: So, you're saying that, within each `Kod` value, you want to divide all of the `ItemQTY` values by the smallest within that `Kod`?

Comment: yes this is my goal

Comment: Can you paste your table/list as text rather than picture?

Comment: ItemQTY Kod
1 57-34-01-020
1 57-34-01-020
1 57-34-01-024
1 57-34-01-024
1 57-34-01-024
2 57-34-01-024
2 57-34-01-024
4 57-34-01-024
2 57-34-01-025
1 57-34-01-025
2 57-34-01-032
4 57-34-01-032
2 57-34-01-033
1 57-34-01-033
1 57-34-01-034
2 57-34-01-034
2 57-34-04-012
1 57-34-04-012
2 57-34-06-004
4 57-34-06-004

Comment: Paste it into your question and format it so that it is readable. Thanks